# How do I remove a specific part of a filename in Python?

Tags: python, directory, filenames

I have the folder that contains of several images (let's say 10) in .jpg format. The names of the files are the following:

```
IM001
IM002
IM003
etc.
```

Is there a way to remove certain part of the filename (for example `IM00`) and leave the rest using Python? I only have idea with `os.rename` but I'm not sure if this is the right one.

Thanks!

Comment: You're on the right path with `os.rename` (or `shutil.move`). Get a list of the files (`os.scandir` or `os.listdir`), transform the names, and then perform the renames. You might consider copying to a a different directory instead of a rename (to avoid data loss if you make a mistake while developing it)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that `os.listdir` returns a list in a random order. You might want to use sort the list.

Comment: I would recommend `rename`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39467195/2836621

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fnmatch.filter` to iterate through all files, which are named like you want (in this case `IM001.jpg` as example)

After that, you can easily remove the "IM00" prefix and rename every file.

```py
import fnmatch

# folder from your images - in my case, its inside the bot folder so i just can use "images"
image_folder = "images"

# Iterate through all files in the folder that match the pattern "IM00*.jpg"
for filename in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(image_folder), "*IM00*.jpg"):

    # Remove the "IM00" prefix, just keep the last number
    new_filename = filename[4:]
            
    # rename the file
    os.rename(os.path.join(image_folder, filename), os.path.join(image_folder, new_filename))
```